# Which episode of Fullmetal Alchemist Brotherhood had a lot of transitions with a black screen and white text?

Tags: fullmetal-alchemist-series, fullmetal-alchemist-brotherhood

I think it was one of the earlier episodes but I can't remember. Maybe it was during a character's backstory or a flashback but it was only in 1 episode.

There was an episode in FMA Brotherhood where the scene would fade to a black screen with white Japanese text appearing vertically, and then fades back to the story, and the whole process is repeated several times throughout the episode as the story progresses. I thought it was during the Ishvalan extermination episode, but Riza Hawkeye was narrating that part so I don't know what other episode it could be.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe you're looking for the Youswell flashback, in episode 38 at around 6:52. This *may* not be what you're looking for, since it doesn't repeat throughout the episode; however, it's the only one I can really think of.

It starts with a black screen stating １９１４年 (year 1914), followed by ユースウェル (Youswell), followed by various shots of the town and Yoki.

[image: １９１４年 ユースウェル]

These shots are interlaced with black screens of white text showing the dialog these characters are saying while in the flashback, since Yoki is narrating the scenario.

Comment: This is definitely the episode. Thank you for your time. :)